# Can anyone explain this 'has no implementation' error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Long story short, this used to work just until recently, and it has this issue whether I run it locally or have the build server deploy it an run. After much stepping through code, I have been able to come up with this:

(this is an owin self-hosted asp application and this is the class called by `WebApp.Start<Startup>(options)`. It breaks here every time:

## This works fine and the application starts

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // controller injector
        //var controllerActivator = new CustomControllerActivator(HostContainer.Current);
        //config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), controllerActivator);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
            "{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        HostContainer.Initialize();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class CustomControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public CustomControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IHttpController;
        request.RegisterForDispose(new DisposeAction(() => _container.Release(controller)));
        return controller;
    }
}
```

## This will throw an exception as soon as the CustomControllerActivator is instantiated

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // controller injector
        var controllerActivator = new CustomControllerActivator(HostContainer.Current);
        //config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), controllerActivator);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
            "{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        HostContainer.Initialize();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class CustomControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public CustomControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller = _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IHttpController;
        request.RegisterForDispose(new DisposeAction(() => _container.Release(controller)));
        return controller;
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two examples is `var controllerActivator = new CustomControllerActivator(HostContainer.Current);` is uncommented on the second example.

The exception that is thrown:

> An exception occurred, System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.MissingMethodException: **Method not found:
>   'System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator.Create**(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor, System.Type)'.
>   at DAS.Services.Reviews.Command.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp(StartContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider
>   services, StartOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
>   at DAS.Services.Reviews.Command.HostingConfiguration.Start(HostControl
>   hostControl) in
>   C:\source\das\Platform\das.services.reviews\src\DAS.Services.Reviews.Command\Host.cs:line
>   40    at
>   Topshelf.Builders.ControlServiceBuilder`1.ControlServiceHandle.Start(HostControl
>   hostControl)    at Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost.Run()

The most frustrating part is that simply uncommenting that instantiation causes the entire startup to fail as soon as `WebApp.Start<Startup>(options)` is called. No break points in Startup.cs will be hit if that line is uncommented. If I comment out that line, then the break points will be hit and every starts fine.

I am stumped. I've tried cleaning the solution and restarting, etc., with no luck. Same issue if it is built and deployed via the build server.

## Update: Here is the host container. Unremarkable imo:

```
public class HostContainer
{
    public static IWindsorContainer Current { get; private set; }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        // this allows multiple registrations of a service (multis will return an array). This
        // must be run before registrations (i.e. before Install() is called)
        Current = new WindsorContainer();
        Current.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(Current.Kernel, true));
        Current.Install(FromAssembly.This());
    }
}
```

## Update 2

So we just ported our core libraries (nuget packages) to netstandard2.0. This problem started to happen after we pulled those new packages into the project. I just noticed that when I build the projects now, I get a slew of warnings in the output window advising me to add a remapping of a number of .Net assemblies to the app.config. Probably around 50 different .net assemblies.

This is making me feel like netstandard2.0 itself is referencing newer framework libraries and there's some sort of tangle-up happening at runtime. If I add binding redirects to the app.config, the messages do not go away, so I'm a bit confused. I'm not sure if this is related.

I cannot recreate this problem if I start a new project from scratch with the same packages (our new netstandard2.0 packages). What am I missing here?

Comment: Note, the placement of the container initialization is where it currently is because I've been moving it around to see if it would have any effect but it doesn't.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are doing a private interface implementation? Could you try making the controller creation function public and removing the `IHttpControllerActivator` from the function name, so `IHttpControllerActivator.Create` becomes `Create`?

Comment: @juunas sorry about that, I didn't realize I left that in. That is just an artifact of me trying everything. Switching it has no effect :/

Comment: @Sinaesthetic and what about `HostContainer.Initialize()`?

Comment: @Nkosi i am working on it. Setting up the same conditions in a new project isn't exactly straight forward. The example here is testable if you set up a new owin hosted webapi project. If I were to post everything here in a runnable form, it would be an entire project. What about `HostContainer.Initialize()?` as mentioned, it doesn't matter where that line goes, there's no effect.

Comment: If I comment out the instantiation of the controller activator, everything starts up fine. The HostContainer initializes properly and resolves all registered dependencies. If I uncomment the line, I can't even step into the ctor because the breakpoints in the startup class never even get hit. There's nothing complex in the host container. I will update post with that code.

Comment: To be more clear, NO breakpoints are hit after `WebApp<Startup>(options)` if that instantiation is uncommented, including the HostContainer. If I move the HostContainer to before the WebApp<Startup(), then it initializes just fine.

Comment: Great so I can't replicate this issue in a new project so something is clearly dorked up and I have no idea what strings to pull on.

Comment: I'm also noticing something new. On build, I get about a hundred of these warnings: `Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll] to Version "4.1.3.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\\net461\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

Comment: @Nkosi as I already stated, I've moved it around with no effect. Plus it's a factory. The container is just a static reference that gets called when a request hits the controller. It would only throw if a request came through before it was initialized. But regardless, if I move it to earlier in the pipeline (where it was previously) it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Please see the first comment in this thread. The create method doesn't even get called until a controller is requested. All the code says is to store the reference so that create can use it when called. The field is still allocated even if null. But it doesn't matter when I initialize it because it has no effect. I can initialize it as the very first step of this entire change and it changes nothing.

Comment: Yes, I know it will be null. It's just irrelevant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an assembly binding issue that isn't presenting in a very helpful manner.

Comment: you could try deleting the bin and rebuilding, if you have not done so already

Comment: Yeah I did all that first as mentioned in the original post. I may just close this as it's starting to look like a tooling issue. As mentioned, I updated some nuget packages that target netstandard2.0 and it's been hell ever since. On a side note, if i create a new solution and have a .net 4.6.1 console app reference a netstandard2.0 library, the 461 app can't resolve anything in the netstandard library. There's a few tickets open on the sdk repo about this. It may be related.

Comment: Was there any further update to this, I'm having exactly the same problem i.e. referencing netstandard lib, 4.6.1 API project using Castle Windsor controller activator?

Comment: @DanKennedy sorry for the late reply. I added my finding as an answer

Comment: Fixing the warnings solved the problem for me. It's at least worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't have a solid answer for this, but the way that I got it to work eventually, was to add net461 as an additional targetframework in the netstandard library. It would seem that if you mix the two, some oddness happens. I don't know what's actually happening, but it's almost as if .net sees that there's a netstandard library in the dependency graph and then looks for an implementation, but for the entire process, defaulting to netcore. So if something wasn't implemented in netcore, it'll throw the not implemented exception. I'm assuming that by adding 461 as a target framework, "it" knows to try that as an implementation first.